# 2 arguments that prove$(\mathbb{C}-\{0\},.)\not\simeq(\mathbb{R-\{0\}},.)$.

Tags: group-theory

> Find two arguments to justify $(\mathbb{C}-\{0\},.)\not\simeq(\mathbb{R-\{0\}},.)$.

An isomorphism implies that there exist $f:\mathbb{C}-\{0\}\to\mathbb{R-\{0\}}$. such that f is bijective and f is a homomorphism.

**1)** Since the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}\subset\mathbb{C}$ and the cardinality of $\mathbb{C}$ is higher than the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$, the function cannot be surjectivce hence not bijective.

**2)** Let´s assume $f$ is a homomorphism. If I pick the unitary root $i=\sqrt{-1}$, the order of $i$ would be 4, and there is no element in $\mathbb{R}$ whose order is $4$.

**Question:**

I am not sure about the first point since the both groups are innumerable. Is it right? What other arguments could I come up with?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cardinality of $\mathbb C$ is the same as the cardinality of $\mathbb R$. The second argument is correct.

Comment: @user8734617            Thanks for the reply! What other argument should I consider? I do not know how to test if it is a homomorphism since I do not have a function.

Comment: Its not very diffeernt from 2), but you could use that $\Bbb R^\times$ has a subgroup of index $2$, whereas $\Bbb C^\times$ does not (because every element is the square of some element)

Comment: For $n>2$ there are $n$ complex $n$th roots of $1$ but not nearly that many real roots.

Comment: Or, equivalently, the torsion subgroup of $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ is of order $2$, and the torsion subgroup of $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ is infinite.

Comment: Your title is correct if you are looking for a homeomorphism.

Comment: @GuyFsone I guess it is right once I have $\not\simeq$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$\mathbb{R}\subset\mathbb{C}$$ does not mean that the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$ is less than the cardinality of $ \mathbb{C}$.

So the cardinality argument does not work.

In fact they have the same cardinality.

The argument using the order of $i$ is a valid argument. An isomorphism should keep orders unchanged.